# Bash script that pulls subfolder from github

Tags: github, git-bash

I've made a simple script in bash to get subfolders from my repo on GitHub.
The problem i'm having is that I want to be able to run the script several times getting several subfolders. The script currently run once. Then i get the message "branch master already up to date" how can I change it so this does not happen and I can pull several folders?

```
getFolder() 
{
    repository="$1"
    folder="$2"
    remote="$3"
    branch="$4"
    if [ "$repository" = school ]
    then
        repository=https://github.com/mergin/School
    fi
    git init
    git remote add "$remote" "$repository"
    git config core.sparsecheckout true
    echo "$folder"/ > .git/info/sparse-checkout
    git pull "$remote" "$branch"
}
```

This is the current function that i use.